# Set the Activity Class in Intellij Idea 10.5 for Running Android App on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, intellij-idea

Recently I created and application under eclipse and it worked just fine later on I tried to transfer the codes to Intellij idea 10.5 and what I did is removing the Original MyActivity.java and replace it with the class I made under eclipse...
Now every time I try to run my app it says that I need to define the Android Activity class and when I select that file it says that the class is not Acceptable.

Since I look at the codes in the original MyActivity class and my own class everything looks similar and I didn't change the structure of an activity class... so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Does your class extend `Activity`?

If the class meets the above requirements, you will be able to specify it in Android Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: I guess the problem was activity in Manifest. since I recreate the whole class problem solved. Thanks a lot.